# iPhone - Changing UITabBarItem title after is customized in More section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar with 8 items in my xib. I have linked those UITabBarItems in my code, so I do the localization inside the viewDidLoad method of my main window UITabBarController. 
eg. tabBarItem1.title = NSLocalizedString(@"TAB1");

My problem is that after I changed the order in the More-Configure section, the items that were not at the front keep their original non-localized title from the .xib file.

Any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each view controller, you could have them set their title with something like

```
[[self tabBarItem] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"TAB1")];
```

That might help keep your app from getting confused. I think that a tabBarItem is one of things you can just reference (like setting a title in a navigationcontroller).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work for me. When I configure the more section, if I drag the icon in the 4 shown items, I can see the original title. Edit: If I restart the application and the tab is between the 4 visible the title is changed.

Comment: So, it's eventually making the change? If that's so, I would experiment with placing the code into different methods (viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, etc.). Sorry I can't be more specific but without looking at your code itself it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can set all the UITabBar icons in an easy way.You can do this in the viewWillAppear method:

```
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Aitul", @"comment")];

[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Aitor", @"comment")];

[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Eibar", @"comment")];

[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Primeran", @"comment")];
```

Answer (score 0):

I point a solution. The ideal could be to change the tabBarItem title on **didEndCustomizingViewControllers**.

```
self.selectedIndex = 3;
[self.selectedViewController.tabBarItem setTitle:@"SSDDD"];
```

That works, but if I use a non static string, for example NSLocalizedString() method, it does not. Also works for localized strings that were in the 4 visible tab items. Seems very weird.

Comment: Basically, the problem was that the customized order of the tabs is saved by the view's title. I did the mapping when the application starts and now works as it should. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problems by 2 steps: :)

First, click TabBarItem of UITabBar in Storyboard or .xib.Then, open Attribute inspector and in section Tab bar Item, choice Identifier to **CUSTOM**.Then, set **Tag** (in my case: 0, 1, 2) Finally, connect outlet this TabBar to ViewController. In my case:

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;`

Second, open ViewController.m in viewDidLoad: method

```
for (UITabBarItem *tabBarItem in [self.tabBar items]){
    NSInteger tag = tabBarItem.tag;
    switch(tag){
               case 0:
            [tabBarItem setTitle:@"Title 1"];
            break;
               case 1:
            [tabBarItem setTitle:@"Title 2"];
            break;
               case 2:
            [tabBarItem setTitle:@"Title 3"];
            break;
}
```

P/S: My english write skills is bad. Sorry if it makes you feel uncomfortable